# What is the best way to get a specific neighbor to move back into a town in Animal Crossing Wild World

Tags: animal-crossing-wild-world

Melba was her favorite character and, by some oversight, she let the character move out of her town a couple of years ago.  She has played a number of in-game years doing nothing (she is near 100% completion) but trying to get Melba to move back in.

She really wants this to happen.

I have read of methods online that describe possible venues for [editing a game save](http://www.angelfire.com/stars5/tkcpics2/wildworld/#faqs) or [forcing a move of a character](http://www.aibohack.com/nds/ac_monkeymove.htm) from another town, but the sites describing these methods are very old (~2006) and various links within the articles describing the processes are dead.

*I was wondering if anyone here could suggest the best way to get a specific neighbor (Melba) to move back into a town in Animal Crossing Wild World.*  I am willing to buy a second DS, second game, any game-save-copying-hardware, or anything else I need to make this happen (would it be better to find someone online who has the character and try to make it move that way?  (I'm not very familiar with the wifi abilities of Wild World)).  I just need a trusted method for making this happen.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're willing to buy a new DS/Game to get Melba back?? May I ask what is so great about Melba?

Comment: She wants it, I want to get it for her.  I don't know exactly - she just likes the character?

Answer (score 2):

Well interestingly enough when a villager moves out of your town they are still saved as game data. So if you visit another town that chactor's data can be swapped with a friend's. If the character is moving away from the town it moved to, you can visit the town again and data can be swapped again. This only works if the friend has Melba. If you do happen to buy the game again and you can keep creating new towns until Melba appears in one of them it will be a new Melba tho. :/

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no sure way of getting any villager back. When a villager moves out, the new villager is chosen at random.

However, if you have a friend with that villager in their town, then connecting to their town and talking to that villager will increase the likelihood of that particular villager moving in.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Nintendo is releasing Amiibo support for Animal Crossing New Leaf this fall: http://www.nintendo.com/amiibo/games/detail/animal-crossing-new-leaf-3ds

While this doesn't help Animal Crossing Wild World players, I thought it'd be something worth mentioning here.

This will grant players the ability to 'force' a character to visit your town.  When the character visits your town you will be able to encourage them to move in through standard methods.